# Why is time.time() not monotonically increasing in an async loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, python-asyncio

I have the code below inside a test file in my app.

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_async_time(iters=50000):
    last_now = time.time()

    for i in range(iters):
        current_now = time.time()
        if current_now < last_now:
            print(f"Failed at iteration {i}")
            print(f"{current_now} < {last_now}")
            assert False

        last_now = current_now

        await asyncio.sleep(random.random() * 0.0001)

    assert True
```

I realize it's not actually testing anything, this is just the only way I could find to reproduce an error occurring in my app.  The error is as follows: if the current time is retrieved in a loop where an async function is awaited, sometimes later loop iterations will show earlier times.  Also, the error occurs only intermittently.  Am I just confused in my understanding of `await`?  I thought that `await` would not return until the async function has completed, so consecutive loop iterations would always show increasing times.

Edit:
I now believe this may be an issue with Docker, and particularly Docker Desktop on Mac.  I neglected to consider or mention that I was running this code on a Docker container on my local Mac, since I did not think that was relevant.  However, the error only seems to occur in a container and not on my host OS.  Indeed, it occurs event without any asynchronous code, so I was wrong in my judgment that the async code was the source of the problem.  I have the code in a repo here: https://github.com/tclarke13/container_tests

Feel free to see if the error occurs on your machine by performing `make run` inside the main repo folder.

Comment: Are you sure your clock isn't being resynced via NTP and messing with the reported time? This is why `time.monotonic()` (or `time.monotonic_ns()`) exists, to avoid issues like that by guaranteeing a monotonically increasing clock. It's not epoch time (the reference point is undefined), so you can't convert it to a true calendar date/time, but differences between measurements would be consistently monotonic.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I had considered that my `time.time()` may be "wrong", per se, since my event loop time did seem to not have this error.  Also I was not aware of the `time.monotonic()` function, thanks for that.  But I still don't know why my time would be resynced via NTP, as the time it takes to run this function is only 10 -20 seconds, a good bit less than the average NTP polling time.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem likely. It does look like the event loop provides [a monotonic `.time()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.time) as well that may make more sense to use in this case, but I agree it doesn't seem like, in the absence of system clock adjustments, you should be seeing a discrepancy.

Comment: *But I still don't know why my time would be resynced via NTP, as the time it takes to run this function is only 10 -20 seconds* - the polling interval is irrelevant, NTP spreads its correction over a longer period to minimize disturbance to applications, which is why you can only detect it in tight loops.

Comment: A nitpick from the I-must-be-fun-at-parties department: values aren't expected to be monotonically increasing, but monotonically _non-decreasing_, which is what your code tests for. Getting the same value just means your code is faster than the granularity of the timer.

Comment: @user4815162342 You're right that I have `<` rather than `<=`, implying that it is testing for non-decreasing rather than increasing, but I should have clarified that I am indeed getting smaller values, not just equal values.

Comment: What I don't understand about this question is how it is related to `await`, or even to Python? `time.time()` just reports wallclock time, it's not controlled by asyncio. Your wallclock time occasionally slips backwards for very minor amounts, which is either perfectly normal or an issue with your system configuration (I suspect the former). Even if you were confused about `await` semantics, it still wouldn't be able to turn back time, something else is doing that.

Comment: @user4815162342. You're right about it not involving async, or potentially even Python.  It may be an issue with my running it in a container, which I didn't consider.  Check out my edit for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried separating your program from the pytest framework?  I ran the following program on Win10 with Python3.8:

```
import time
import random
import asyncio

async def test_async_time(iters=50000):
    last_now = time.time()
    t0 = last_now

    for i in range(iters):
        current_now = time.time()
        if current_now < last_now:
            print(f"Failed at iteration {i}")
            print(f"{current_now} < {last_now}")

        last_now = current_now

        await asyncio.sleep(random.random() * 0.0001)
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print(f"Pass {i}")
    print(t0 - last_now)

asyncio.run(test_async_time())
```

It ran without printing anything except the period "Pass xxx" message, which I added so I could monitor progress.  It took 795 seconds, not the 10-20 that you observe.  That corresponds to about 60 loop iterations per second.  That suggests that the granularity of the asycnio.wait() function on Win10 is about 16.7 ms.

I find it hard to believe that you can execute the code inside the for loop in 400 microseconds, which is what it would take to do 50000 iterations in 20 seconds.  Something looks fishy here, but I can't guess what it is, since your results are so different from mine.

Comment: I'm surprised your run took so long.  If you just take the expected amount of time the `asyncio.sleep` will take (0.00005 s) and multiply by the number of iterations (50000), you get 2.5 s total, so I don't feel that my total runtime is far off.

Comment: I agree with @TaylorClarke regarding the timing - while Python is not the fastest language around, 0.4ms is a lot of time, and quite sufficient for an event loop iteration. If the granularity of the asyncio event loop is indeed 16ms on Windows, that should be reported as a bug.